# Contar filas - resultado sentencia en la consulta

Tags: mysql, select

Necesito contar las filas que da como resultado esta sentencia (que funciona correctamente y sé que devuelve un único valor):

```
SELECT comp.descripcion 
FROM componente AS comp, pieza AS pza, pieza_equipo AS pzaequip, equipos AS equip 
WHERE comp.codigo = pza.codigo_componente AND 
pza.codigo = pzaequip.codigo_pieza AND 
pzaequip.codigo_equipo = equip.codigo AND 
comp.familia = 'CAJA' AND 
equip.codigo = 'eq_1101'
```

Siempre va a devolver o una fila o ninguna, eso es lo que me interesa saber.

Comment: Hola, lo puedes hacer con `count(*)`, ponlo en vez de `comp.descripcion`

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS asi:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS comp.descripcion 
FROM componente AS comp, pieza AS pza, pieza_equipo AS pzaequip, equipos AS equip 
WHERE comp.codigo = pza.codigo_componente AND 
pza.codigo = pzaequip.codigo_pieza AND 
pzaequip.codigo_equipo = equip.codigo AND 
comp.familia = 'CAJA' AND 
equip.codigo = 'eq_1101'
```

Luego para saber cuantas filas son retornadas por tu query corre:

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

Comment: y como puedo incorporarlo en un código en Java?

Comment: No habias mencionado Java, pero lo correrias como cualquier otro query.  Si te es mas facil, quizas sea mejor para ti usar count(*)